# Textarea contenteditable

Tags: html, textarea, contenteditable

I am trying to make a textarea content editable and I am failing. I am using this code:

```
<textarea id='' class='' name='notes' rows='12' cols='67' contenteditable='true' ></textarea>
```

I am expecting a result like http://html5demos.com/contenteditable

Does anyone have an idea why it's not working?

**Edit:**

I am doing this because I am trying to do a oneliner to add a control to a form in which (HTML) formatted content can be pasted and retain its formatting. I am trying to do this without fuss and without javascript code. It appears this is not possible. I will close this question in a day if no further input to the contrary is added.

Answer (score 4):

Have you set the right doctype at the top of your page? For HTML5 you need the following doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Also, why a textarea? textareas are already editable.

Comment: As on Ben's post, 
 I was hoping for a WYSIWYG where one can paste bold text etc and retain formatting . The reason for this is that I need to post this in a form submit after it's been edited.

Comment: The form will not submit the formatting. Instead put it in a div and use onSumbit to read the innerHTML of the div.

Comment: Thanks Marius. I was hoping to KISS, but there we go.

Answer (score 1):

They are not using a textarea, textareas are already editable. This is what they are using

```
<section contenteditable="true" id="editable">
    <h2>Go ahead, edit away!</h2>
    <p>Here's a typical paragraph element</p>
    <ol>
      <li>and now a list</li>
      <li>with only</li>
      <li>three items</li>
    </ol>
  </section>
```

Comment: I was hoping for a WYSIWYG where one can paste bold text etc. The reason for this is that I need to post this in a form submit after it's been edited.

Comment: I need something like this as well. I seen some people actually write its contents to a hidden field, but you would have to do this update each time you make a change or run execCommand

Comment: But section or other similar object does not support native functions like as placeholder, required, etc. The textarea canot support for content editable as html format.

Answer (score 1):

I don't mean to repeat anything, but I've put together a demo that shows what is happening.

http://gist.github.com/210327

Just run that, edit what you wish and click the 'Output Formatted Content' statement to receive an alert message with an output of the actual html-formatted content in the contenteditable element.  As for adding formatting, etc, you'll need to make buttons that call a text-modifying function on whatever is highlighted.  Yeah, that part will be fun.

Nonetheless, I hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for effort, but it's not quite what I needed... because I think what I needed is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Given your comment responses, I would recommend any of the excellent WYSIWYG editors out there. No need to re-invent the wheel, and I don't think `contenteditable` wouldn't have met your needs anyway.

My personal favorite is [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/), but there are many, many others. [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) is also very popular.

Comment: I was hoping for a oneliner to solve my problems (just needed a simple text area that could hold formatted text) but this is apparently not on the cards. Thanks for the suggestion though.